# '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: apt, package-management, files, file-format

'/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

What did I do and how do I fix it?

```
haroldbarnes@ToeJobBob:~$ sudo apt-get update 
N: Ignoring file 'signal-xenial.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Xenial was the codename for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS that is EOSS (*end of standard support*).  We can't see the contents of the file in question (*displayed in your error message*) thus cannot see what's inside it..  You edit it & correct the problem OR just remove it as the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty on a clean install; thus it was added by a user with `sudo` privileges post-install.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM is *supported* elsewhere if you need support; but *xenial* is off-topic now on this site.

Comment: The `N:` message is just a notification. The `E:` message is because of the extraneous “smart” quotes

Comment: @guiverc OP isn't using Xenial, the signal.org third party repositories calls its distribution "Xenial" regardless of the OS you install it on - see https://signal.org/en/download/linux/

Comment: The OP should have stated, as the only provided details in the post clearly state off-topic *xenial*, so why should we assume something different @thomasrutter?  Xenial is a *reserved codename* in Ubuntu.

Comment: OP is a new contributor, be nice.  Furthermore the only appearance of the term "Xenial" in the post was part of third party software, not Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have made a mistake in the process of install Signal following these instructions.

https://signal.org/en/download/linux/

In order to start over, you can remove anything related to signal from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` that has "signal" in its name and start over.

You may also need to do the same with `/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg` if that has similar problems.

Note that Signal's third party repository calls its distribution "Xenial" but that appears unrelated to the Ubuntu release of the same name, it's just how Signal has chosen to call it.

Answer (score 0):

**The first thing**

You don't need this file `signal-xenial.list.save.1`, so remove this file.

**To fix this error**

> E: The list of sources could not be read

Couse you're not set keyring.gpg correctly.

To Get public software signing key and install the Signal's third party repository. Please following :

```
$ wget -O - https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt/keys.asc | gpg --dearmor > signal-desktop-keyring.gpg
$ sudo cp signal-desktop-keyring.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/
$ sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg
$ echo 'deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
```

**To** run Signal desktop :

```
//Sets Permissions    
$ sudo chmod 4755 /opt/Signal/chrome-sandbox
//Finally run    
$ signal-desktop
```

**Or** alternative launch it without appointment rights 4755.

```
$ signal-desktop --no-sandbox
```

Should be run like this :

[image: signal-desktop]
**Related**

- https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/5865
- https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues/5567

Hope this helps.